# selenium python output dismiss <br>

Tags: python, selenium

I want to take web information:

```
<span id="dnn_ctr778_MyAccountInfo_lblFormattedAddrExternal">1000 Nicollet Mall <br>TPS-2086<br>Minneapolis, MN 55403</span>
```

By using selenium:

```
customer_address_u = browser.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr778_MyAccountInfo_lblFormattedAddrExternal")
customer_address = customer_address_u.text
```

the output is:

```
1000 Nicollet Mall
TPS-2086
Minneapolis, MN 55403
```

How can I make it in one line?

```
1000 Nicollet Mall TPS-2086 Minneapolis, MN 55403
```

Comment: The easiest way is replace all `\n` by a space like this: `customer_address = customer_address_u.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()`. But maybe this isn't the  correct solution that you're looking for?